# PHP + MongoHQ : MongoCursorException

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to use mongodb with PHP. 
For that, I have created a MongoHQ instance, but for some reasons when I try to insert something or any other operation from my php server I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'unauthorized for db [datab] lock type: -1 ' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\application\controllers\Stat.ctrl.php:56 
Stack trace: 
  #0 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\application\controllers\Stat.ctrl.php(56): MongoCursor->rewind() 
  #1 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\index.php(105): Stat->index() 
  #2 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\application\controllers\Stat.ctrl.php on line 56
```

Does anyone know where it can be coming from?

This is the php code I'm using:

```
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';

try
{
$link = new Mongo( "flame.mongohq.com:27022/datab -u <".$username."> -p <".$password.">" );

//MongoDB::authenticate ( $username , $password )
//$link = new Mongo();
}
catch(MongoConnectionException $e)
{
die('Could not connect. Check to make sure MongoDB is running.');
}
$db = $link->datab;
$col = $db->order;

try
{
// Insert a document (row) into the collection (table)
$doc = array('login' => 'jsmith', 'password' => ' 5f4dcc3b5aa765', 'email' => 'jsmith@example.com');
$col->insert($doc, true);

$doc = array('login' => 'psmith', 'password' => ' 5f4dcc3b', 'email' => 'psmith@example.com');
$col->insert($doc, true);
}
catch(MongoCursorException $e)
{
echo 'Je suis la!';
}

// Get the id of last insert
$id = $doc['_id'];

// Get all documents
$res = $col->find();

echo 'All documents:<br/>';

foreach($res as $doc)
{
echo '<pre>';
print_r($doc);
echo '</pre>';
}

// Query for the document matching the last insert ID
$doc = $col->findone(array('_id' => $id));

echo 'Single document (_id = $id):<br/><pre>';
print_r($doc);

// Update a document
$col->update(array('_id' => $id), array('$set' => array('password' => 'b497dd1a701a33033620780d')));

// Query the updated docuemnt
$doc = $col->findone(array('_id' => $id));

echo 'Updated docuement:<br/><pre>';
print_r($doc);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're connecting to MongoHQ? It looks like you're either not trying to authenticate, or are providing the wrong credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the connection format MongoDB uses.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php.

You probably need to change it to something like:

```
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$username:$password@flame.mongohq.com:27022/datab");
```